# link to popup compare list in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a link to show the compare list.

The list should open in a smaler kind of popup.

The following link i have copy from top.phtml an edit it an put it into the header-template.

```
<a id="btccart" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('cartpro')->__('View Comparison');?>" href="javascript:void('0')" onclick="$('confirmbox').innerHTML='';$('fancybox-wrap-clone').setStyle({display:'none'});$('options').setStyle({display:'none'});'+strclick+'"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('cartpro')->__('View Comparison');?></span></a>
```

But the link wont work - what did i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it out and i use the following link, for me it works fine.

```
<a data-original-title="<?php echo Mage::helper('cartpro')->__('View Comparison');?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="btccart" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('cartpro')->__('View Comparison');?>" href="javascript:void('0')" onclick="$('confirmbox').innerHTML='';$('fancybox-wrap-clone').setStyle({display:'none'});$('options').setStyle({display:'none'});popWin('http://www.domain.com/catalog/product_compare/index/,,/','compare','top:0,left:0,width=820,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" class="btn-vergleich">&nbsp;</a>
```